# bindfs on OSX limited to 24 mounts

Tags: macos, mount

I'm trying to use [bindfs](http://bindfs.org/) on OS X 10.9.

Here is a sample one-liner to mount 25 directories into another:

```
for elem in $(seq 1 25); do 
  dir=blah${elem};
  mkdir -p /tmp/space/$dir; 
  mkdir -p /tmp/mount/$dir; 
  bindfs /tmp/space/$dir /tmp/mount/$dir; 
done
```

Running this code, gives me the following error message:

```
fuse: failed to open device: Resource busy
```

I can see that 24 of the mounts were successful by running the `mount` command and counting 24 osxfuse entries.

Does anyone have any idea what limitation I'm running into? Are there any alternatives to mounting one directory inside of another?

Answer (score 0):

did you find an answer? I'm investigating the same issue.

In the meantime you can use symlinks. Even hardlinking directories apparently - although that is considered dangerous.